# Writing a csv file python

Tags: python, excel, csv

So i have a list:

```
>>> print references
>>> ['Reference xxx-xxx-xxx-007 ', 'Reference xxx-xxx-xxx-001 ', 'Reference xxx-xxx-xxxx-00-398 ', 'Reference xxx-xxx-xxxx-00-399']
```

(The list is much longer than that)

I need to write a CSV file wich would look this:

```
Column 1:
Reference xxx-xxx-xxx-007
Reference xxx-xxx-xxx-001
[...]
```

I tried this :

```
c = csv.writer(open("file.csv", 'w'))
for item in references:
    c.writerows(item)
Or:
for i in range(0,len(references)):
    c.writerow(references[i])
```

But when I open the csv file created, I get a window asking me to choose the delimiter
No matter what, I have something like
R,e,f,e,r,e,n,c,es

Comment: How do you want your output to look like? What are the rules?

Comment: I don't know the library you use, but did you try `c.writerows(references)` (instead of the `for` loop) ?

Comment: @Fabien: The [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library comes with Python; you should know it.

Comment: @abarnert didn't know that was in the default libs ; thanks for the information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`writerows`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) takes a sequence of rows, each of which is a sequence of columns, and writes them out.

But you only have a single `list` of values. So, you want:

```
for item in references:
    c.writerow([item])
```

Or, if you want a one-liner:

```
c.writerows([item] for item in references)
```

The point is, each row has to be a sequence; as it is, each row is just a single string.

So, why are you getting `R,e,f,e,r,e,n,c,e,…` instead of an error? Well, a string is a sequence of characters (each of which is itself a string). So, if you try to treat `"Reference"` as a sequence, it's the same as `['R', 'e', 'f', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'e']`.

---

In a comment, you asked:

> Now what if I want to write something in the second column ?

Well, then each row has to be a `list` of two items. For example, let's say you had this:

```
references = ['Reference xxx-xxx-xxx-007 ', 'Reference xxx-xxx-xxx-001 ']
descriptions = ['shiny thingy', 'dull thingy']
```

You could do this:

```
csv.writerows(zip(references, descriptions))
```

Or, if you had this:

```
references = ['Reference xxx-xxx-xxx-007 ', 'Reference xxx-xxx-xxx-001 ', 'Reference xxx-xxx-xxx-001 ']
descriptions = {'Reference xxx-xxx-xxx-007 ': 'shiny thingy', 
                'Reference xxx-xxx-xxx-001 ': 'dull thingy']}
```

You could do this:

```
csv.writerows((reference, descriptions[reference]) for reference in references)
```

The key is, find a way to create that `list` of `list`s—if you can't figure it out all in your head, you can `print` all the intermediate steps to see what they look like—and then you can call `writerows`. If you can only figure out how to create each single row one at a time, use a loop and call `writerow` on each row.

---

But what if you get the first column values, and then later get the second column values?

Well, you can't add a column to a CSV; you can only write by row, not column by column. But there are a few ways around that.

First, you can just write the table in transposed order:

```
c.writerow(references)
c.writerow(descriptions)
```

Then, after you import it into Excel, just transpose it back.

Second, instead of writing the values as you get them, gather them up into a list, and write everything at the end. Something like this:

```
rows=[[item] for item in references] 
# now rows is a 1-column table
# ... later
for i, description in enumerate(descriptions):
    values[i].append(description)
# and now rows is a 2-column table
c.writerows(rows)
```

If worst comes to worst, you can always write the CSV, then read it back and write a new one to add the column:

```
with open('temp.csv', 'w') as temp:
    writer=csv.writer(temp)
    # write out the references
# later
with open('temp.csv') as temp, open('real.csv', 'w') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(temp)
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(row + [description] for (row, description) in zip(reader, descriptions))
```

Comment: Thank you, the second option works perfectly. Each reference is in a row. Now what if I want to write something in the second column ?

Comment: @Yanis: Then you just create a `list` of `list`s of two items each, instead of a `list` of `list`s of one item each. Let me add an example to the answer.

Comment: EDIT: OK got it ! csv.writerows(zip(references, descriptions)) zip ?

Comment: You can't write one column, then the next column; you have to write one row, then the next row. But… let me edit the answer again.

Comment: @Yanis: Exactly! What's the question at the end for? Do you not know what `zip` does? Play with it in the interactive interpreter, or print out the intermediate results from your script; you'll get the idea pretty quickly. (One caveat: If you're using Python 3.x, you'll want to print `list(zip(x, y))`, not just `zip(x, y)`. Try it both ways and you'll see why you need to convert to a `list`.)

Comment: Thank you it's **very** well explained. I will try this, I might come back later haha !

Answer (score 1):

`writerow` writes the elements of an iterable in different columns. This means that if your provide a tuple, each element will go in one column. If you provide a String, each letter will go in one column. If you want all the content in the same column do the following:

```
c = csv.writer(open("file.csv", 'wb'))
c.writerows(references)
```

or

```
for item in references:
    c.writerow(references)
```

Comment: Since `references` is just a `list` of strings, the first one still breaks each string up into characters. And the second one writes N identical copies of a row with N columns, instead of N different rows of 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = csv.writer(open("file.csv", 'w'))
c.writerows(["Reference"])

# cat file.csv
R,e,f,e,r,e,n,c,e
```

but

```
c = csv.writer(open("file.csv", 'w'))
c.writerow(["Reference"])


# cat file.csv
Reference
```

Would work as others have said.

My original answer was flawed due to confusing `writerow` and `writerows`.

Comment: Why would you do `writerows([item])` instead of just `writerow(item)`? It's the same thing, but more complicated…

Comment: My bad. I tested using ``writerow`` and got the OPs result with a string but then told them to change it for ``writerows``.